# install STS for Eclipse 3.8 on eclipse Neon

Tags: java, eclipse

I've installed Eclipse neon on my laptop but I also need STS. I've had a look online and  [found this](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tool-suite-sts-eclipse). Here it says that this version of STS (not specified on the webpage) is fine up to eclipse oxygen, but if I drag and drop the installer in my eclipse it says that that STS version for Eclipse is the 3.8. Now, is it OK and safe to proceed and effectively install STS 3.8 on Eclipse 4.6.2 (neon)?
thanks

Comment: The 3.8 is the STS release number which is not related to the Eclipse release number.

Comment: OK thanks for clarifying that, I will go ahead and install it.